# Computer Status (Sleep, Hibernate, Locked, etc) Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check the **current state** **of the Computer. Hibernate, Sleep, onStand-by  Locked, etc**

I Just want to Ask on how to get the current status of my computer using C#?
I have already get when the computer is locked by detecting the LockApp process but I can't get if it is on sleep mode, or hibernate.

I want to try a project that will run using the task scheduler and check the **current state of the computer** and will show on the console.

Please note that I is to detect the state of the computer when my project runs.
Thank you.
And sorry for my bad English. :)

```
//Will return true if the Computer is Locked
public bool Lock()
{
    Boolean locked = false;
    Process[] LockApp = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process theprocess in LockApp)
    {
        if (theprocess.ProcessName == "LockApp")
        {
            locked = true;
            Console.WriteLine("LockApp: " + locked.ToString());
        }
    }
    return locked;
}
//Will return true if still on Startuptime (+5min)
public bool onStartupTime()
{
    bool oST = false;
    DateTime ST = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(- 
    Environment.TickCount);
    DateTime Less = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
    DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine(ST.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    Console.WriteLine(Less.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    Console.WriteLine(Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

    if (ST >= Less)
    {
        oST = true;
    }

    return oST;
}
```

OnStartup(-5mins): true or false
Lock: true or false
Sleep: true or false
hibernate: true or false

Comment: When the computer is in hibernate, sleep or standby, no process is actively running. So you cannot report these (but you may be able to detect going into or out of these states)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, Thanks for the info. So I need to check the event when it is changing state right?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/cd184e2a-4c88-4f2e-8b39-f7ab3836eec7/how-to-identify-if-a-computer-is-about-to-sleep-or-hibernate-using-c-and-visual-studio-2010?forum=powermanagement), you can do it using `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged`. An example of using is also posted there:

```
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += new PowerModeChangedEventHandler(OnPowerModeChanged);


    private static void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Mode)
        {
            case PowerModes.Resume:
                MessageBox.Show("PowerMode: OS is resuming from suspended state");
                break;

            case PowerModes.Suspend:
                MessageBox.Show("PowerMode: OS is about to be suspended");
                break;
        }
    }
```